# How can you view the Ripple orderbook without being logged in?

Tags: ripple

Is there a service that exposes the orderbook without requiring a Ripple account?

Comment: Not the orders (at least yet), but graphs of the market are available at https://ripplecharts.com/ and http://bitcoincharts.com/

Comment: You can get the orderbook via a ruby command line tool: https://github.com/arvicco/rippler or make your own using websockets and the published API (I have one in Go).

Answer (score 1):

http://xrp.webr3.org/usd-xrp has the orderbooks of Bitstamp BTC/XRP, Bitstamp USD/XRP. https://ripplewise.info has Bitstamp, SnapSwap, RippleChina orderbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can view all the markets that trade Ripple without logging in on the Bitango market search page: http://bitdango.com/markets?quoteCurrencies=XRP